# How to install the latest version of Ruby and Ruby on Rails in Ubuntu?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu-11.04, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby1.9

I installed Ruby with the command `apt-get install ruby1.9.1`, but when I enter `ruby` in the console, nothing happens.

I have to use the command

```
ruby1.9.1-v

ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [i686-linux]
```

But how do I call it with `ruby` and not `ruby1.9.1`? And how do I install Rails?

Comment: What happens if you do "which ruby", does it show as being installed? Does "ruby -v" show the right version number?

Comment: Install: sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-full
ruby -v

Comment: Program 'ruby' is not installed.

Comment: When you type "sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-full" in a terminal does anything happen?

Comment: I'm a little confused by your update. If you want to install rails please use RVM - http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/ - to install rails and any other gems. It is a package manager and will save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 18):

### How to get a current Ruby version without messing up your system

Do not mess with your system Ruby, but instead install a current version with either `rbenv` or RVM. [I prefer the first](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/wiki/Why-rbenv%3F), but both work fine. Note that you can only install one of those at a time.

With such a Ruby version manager, you'll never have to type `sudo` again to install (or uninstall) a Gem, and you can keep different versions for different projects. You can safely remove these versions again.

Please make sure to read the `README`s of those tools, at least once.

### Method 1 – `rbenv`

[rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) is a version manager for Ruby. It allows you to install a Ruby version alongside your original system Ruby, which means you cannot mess up that one, and you can easily upgrade versions.

To install it, use the [`rbenv-installer`](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-installer#rbenv-installer). Make sure to restart your shell once it's installed, and that the `rbenv` function works.

Then, once rbenv is installed, run `rbenv install -l`. This gives you a list of available Rubies. Install your chosen one with:

```
rbenv install 2.5.1
```

Now choose this one as your default:

```
rbenv global 2.5.1
```

As soon as this is done, `gem` can be used to run:

```
gem install rails
```

If the above does not work, you might be missing required packages for building from source. See [here](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/wiki#suggested-build-environment) for a list of packages that you might want to install. On Ubuntu, these include:

```
sudo apt install autoconf bison build-essential libssl-dev libyaml-dev libreadline6-dev zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libffi-dev libgdbm5 libgdbm-dev
```

### Method 2 – RVM

You can also install Ruby over [RVM](https://rvm.io/). Here as well, you don't need to `sudo` anything, and you'll be able to get more recent versions of Ruby alongside the system one.

Read the [installation instructions](https://rvm.io/rvm/install) for your system.

After installation, you can install Rubies with a simple command. First, check `rvm list known` to get the list of installable versions. Now install your choice:

```
rvm install 2.5.1
```

Then, set it as the default Ruby version for your user:

```
rvm use 2.5.1 --default
```

Now you can install Rails over `gem`:

```
gem install rails
```

Comment: Also, if you are using RVM do not use sudo.

Comment: FYI - in the `apt-get install` step, you have `lib1g` above when this should be `zlib1g`. I also installed rvm with apt-get. This sets things up nicely and doesn't require you to edit your bashrc. I'm not sure if this is the best approach as I haven't tried `$rvm get latest` yet.

Comment: @slhck StackExchange won't let me make the edit to the `apt-get install` step - edits have to be more than 6 chars and we only need to change 1. And, I'm not a fan of `sudo apt-get install ruby-rvm` so far. I'm getting weird bugs due to permissions (i.e. $rvm install 1.9.3 complains because it's trying to write to a directory owned by root). It looks like keeping rvm in userspace is the best option.

Comment: I feel like [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) (and [ruby-build](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build)) should be mentioned here for completeness. It's an alternative to RVM with a cleaner method of hooking into your shell (but is practically not necessarily very different).

Comment: I just did `sudo apt-get install ruby-rvm` -- is there still a need to do the crazy bash stuff to beginrescueend, whatever that is?

Comment: @Jeff No, you'll get RVM already with this package – test it by just running the `rvm` command. I'm not sure whether it is the latest version though, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to install ruby on ubuntu, but installing form the repositories is (currently) not popular. To cleanly get a non-suffixed `ruby`, you should [build ruby yourself or use rvm](http://rbjl.net/19-rubybuntu-1-installing-ruby-and-rails-on-ubuntu).