# How to update ruby version 2.4.1 to 2.5.0 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, updates, ruby

I have run the code:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby 2.5.0
```

then:

```
update-alternatives --query ruby
```

which throws error:

```
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for ruby
```

I also used the code:

```
wget http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.5/ruby-2.5.3.tar.gz
tar -xzvf ruby-2.5.3.tar.gz
cd
cd ruby-2.5.3/
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

but this too didn't work as when I run this code to check the version:

```
ruby -v
```

it shows the previous version i.e. `ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-linux]`

this question is repeated but the other solutions didn't work for me. Any suggestion or help will be appreciated.

Comment: "sudo apt-get install ruby 2.5.0" is not valid code. It would try to install a package called "ruby" and a package called "2.5.0". Please show exactly what you have tried and what output you got. What other solutions did not work?

Comment: this is what was mentioned and I have tried, can you please specify the correct code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install the latest version of Ruby and Ruby on Rails in Ubuntu?](https://superuser.com/questions/291693/how-to-install-the-latest-version-of-ruby-and-ruby-on-rails-in-ubuntu)

Comment: You didn't say where that was mentioned. Either way I recommend using `rbenv` or RVM to install a current Ruby.

Comment: [link] (How to install the latest version of Ruby and Ruby on Rails in Ubuntu?)  -this too didn't work for me.

Comment: "this didn't work" is not a proper error description. Please show *exactly* what you have tried and what happened as a result. We're not sitting in front of your computer, so we cannot guess what the problem is. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and [edit] your post with more info.

Comment: @slhck This is the best way to handle this. Don’t attempt to update the core system Ruby but instead use [RVM](https://rvm.io) or [rbenv](https://devhints.io/rbenv). Anything else is a pain to manage at best, headache at worst.

Comment: While installing it through RVM it throws an error `'RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.'` though I have checked the  'Run command as login shell'

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336596/rvm-installation-not-working-rvm-is-not-a-function, but please remember to look for these kinds of errors and see if there is a solution already available online.

Comment: @spd_25 Sounds like you have environment path issues.

Comment: the ruby -v command gives the following output:ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux]